# confusion calculating x/y coordinates based on rotation angle with D3 + svg transformation

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, rotation

new to D3 and SVG and am getting majorly confused why my math for calculating x, y coordinates (of an SVG element position around a circle / clock-face) using the angle of rotation + arc distance... essentially:

1. i create the circle / clock-face (includes a translation):

   ```
   var face = d3.select(".chart").append("g")
       .attr("class", "clock-face")
       .attr('transform','translate(' + width/2 + ',' + (circleRadius + margin) + ')');
   ```
2. i append a "g" element (to contain the data + some visual stuff) to the clock-face & apply a rotation to the individual data point container (based on a linear scale to position elements around a circle):

   ```
   var circleScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([0, data.length])
       .domain([0, 60]);

   // data container
   var bar = face.selectAll('g')
       .data(data)
       .enter().append('g')
       .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
           return 'rotate('  + circleScale(i) + ')';
       })
       .each(function(d, i) {
           // set theta
           d.theta = circleScale(i);
   });
   ```
3. i want to be able to calculate the x/y coordinates of my individual data point container based on it's theta (angle of rotation) value:

   ```
   function calcPosition(centerX, centerY, radius, theta) {
       var coords = {};
       var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(theta);
       var y = centerX + radius * Math.sin(theta);
       coords.x = x;
       coords.y = y;

       return coords;
   };

   var origin = calcPosition(0, 0, circleRadius, d.theta);

   face.append('circle')
       .attr('cx', origin.x)
       .attr('cy', origin.y)
       .attr('r', 5)
       .attr('fill', 'yellow')
   ```

however, this produces the totally wrong x/y coordinates. i believe my trig is correct in calculating x/y coordinates based off the angle of rotation, but something about SVG transformations is buggering it all up... any suggestions?

much thanks!

Comment: Is `theta` in _degrees_ or _radians_?

Comment: @PaulS. good question... original i had the circle scale as such:   var circleScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, data.length]).domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

Comment: but that produced weird results (not correctly mapping to 360 degrees)... however for some reason changing the circle scale to the following worked... i see that this might be the point of my error. but am confused about D3 scales:                                    var circleScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, data.length]).domain([0, 60]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your circle scale, looks like you incorrectly swap between range and domain. The **range** should be either `[0,360]` or `[0,2*Math.PI]`. Note how you currently have `[0,60]`, instead of 360, and that might have been a mistake. *Maybe* the domain should become `[0,data.length]` —— as you currently have for range —— but I'm not sure about the nature of the data and whether that makes sense. I would expect domain to be `[0,12]`, for hours of the day.

As for your `calcPosition` trig stuff, `theta` **has to be** in radians for it to work, which would suggest that your `circleScale` should be in the `[0,2*Math.PI]` range. However, for SVG transform you need to use degrees. So one way or another you'll need to do a bit of converting in one of those instances. Also, you have a bug in `calcPosition`, where `y` should be based on `centerY` not `centerX`.

Finally, I'd recommend calculating all the `d.theta` upfront, in a simple for loop, as opposed to doing so in the `each` function when you render. This is mostly just for separation of concerns and to avoid bugs (like, what would happens if you attempt to access `d.theta` before you render the bars?).